# solaris 8 init script asks for user password

Tags: boot, solaris, su

I've got a script in the Solaris 8 initialization phase, under `/etc/rc3.d`, that contains a `su - username -c "a command"`, but I see thru the boot messages that the su command is asking for the user password. The result is that the boot proceed (there is no console to give su the user password) and the script fails.

The same script on a Solaris 10 works doing everything during the boot.

It is strange that the script run as root asks for a normal user password.

Comment: What does `su - username` run as root do? Have you checked the manpage(s)? It is certainly weird.

Comment: The - option is a shortcut for -l, that is to log in with the same environment of the target user. And it works if run interactively, without asking the password.

Comment: Check as who this script runs, i.e. add some who/whoami/others in there and collect the output [How this reminds me of a 400+ flamewar over at http://lwn.net on myths around systemd, where some insist that the sysvinit mess is easy to debug...]

Comment: Wait a minute, what does Solaris 8 use for organizing boot? It's not the traditional SysV init anymore, is it? And Solaris 10?

Comment: BTW, I got into the habit of using _no_ shortcuts in init (and other system-y) scripts: Don't rely on $PATH, all options fully spelled out, ... This after a few rather unpleasant surprises.

Comment: Don't know Solaris at all, but init must already be running as root, so as @vonbrand says, you need to find out if this script is running as another user.  If it is, maybe (don't know how Solaris works) you could use sudo instead of su and add that user (and that specific action or actions) to /etc/sudoers (using visudo). Then it would just go ahead and run without asking for a password. You'd need to be careful what you permit in sudoers so you don't create a security hole.  That's why you could tell it to allow that user to use only the necessary commands.

Comment: I've placed a whoami in the script and the result is that the script is run by "" (i.e., whoami returns an empty script) when run into the init procedure.

Comment: Are you sure you need the `su`? What happens if you run the script without it? It should be run in a privileged mode by default.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have some really strange custom PAM modules, there's no way that "su" is prompting for a password when run as root.  By using `su - user -c ...` with a dash(-) instead of using `su user -c ...`, your boot script is processing their start-up "dot" files.   It's probably that something in their dot files is invoking another `su` or that the invoked command is actually doing another `su`.

On a related note, for many scripts, it's helpful to put in a line reading `exec < /dev/null`.  This will prevent any attempt to read standard input for most things.  This may not help for boot scripts and `su` though, because unless I misremembering, the Solaris 8 `su` will grab the terminal instead of stdin.

Check the dot files.  And try removing the "-" from `su` so that they aren't processed.  If you have any settings that need to be visible for both interactive use and use by the boot script, consider putting just those settings into a so-called environment file.  The dot files and the boot script can then both source the environment file.  The settings in the environment file will probably change rarely and your boot process is less likely to be impacted by someone munging the dot files.